# Is there a way to revert a wordpress update?

Tags: wordpress

I just upgraded to the new version of wordpress and I lost all of the changes that I had made to the site in editor. All the changes I made in the style.css file are gone.

Is there a way to revert or get those edits back?

It is weird that wordpress does not tell you that you could lose all this these edits if you upgrade.

Comment: Do you have any backups? As far as I know the files are simply replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your hosting provider to roll back the latest backup.

Comment: This is what I needed to do. I contacted the hosting provider and needed to install something call R1 soft host. This costed £2.99 a month, but I cancelled it as soon as I restored and I now use a plug in called Updraft. This lets you do backups to many different storage destinations, such as drop box, google drive and even an ftp. I recommend doing this on website creation and its free :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not weird. WP's auto update will not overwrite a theme other than the default Twenty Ten theme. That's in order to update the default theme with fixes along with WP core files.

Losing customizations to a theme is probably because you modified the default theme rather than make a child theme of it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

You can also safely modify Twenty Ten if you change the name of the theme folder to something other than `twentyten` and also change the info in the style.css header. That will keep WP from recognizing the theme as default and overwriting it on upgrade.

Ask your web host for a backup.